# Get triggering element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, coffeescript

At its core my issue is the following:

```
$('input').click (e) ->
  # do some things conditionally, depending on the event origin
  false

$('a').click ->
  $('input').click()
```

So the issue is, how can I tell who started the event.

Please note that in both of the cases (either clicking the input or the link `e.target` is the same).

Update: I posted the code above here: http://jsfiddle.net/w7faW/1/

Thanks.

Comment: Why the `e.target` is same? Can you elaborate a little more on what you want?

Comment: Please see my jsfiddle. Perhaps I may be doing something wrong, but that's what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters when triggering events programmatically using the [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function:

```
$('input').click (e, target = e.target) ->
  console.log 'target:', target
  false

$('a').click (e) ->
  $('input').trigger 'click', this
```

There i'm passing an optional argument `target` which defaults to `e.target`, and when clicking on the link, the link itself is passed as that parameter. Then you can use that parameter to check which was the triggering element. You can check the different outputs in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvSj6/1/).

---

However, given this simple example, i must say that this solution is probably a bit confusing, i'd prefer just using the same function as a click handler for both elements ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvSj6/2/)):

```
$('input, a').click (e) ->
  console.log 'target:', e.target
  false
```

Or, if you need to do something different for each element and then something in common for both, you can just use another function for that common behavior:

```
$('input').click (e) ->
  # Do something special for the input.
  commonClickHandler this, e

$('a').click (e) ->
  # Do something special for the link.
  commonClickHandler this, e

somethingCommon = (element, event) ->
  # Do something common for both elements.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass extra parameters to the event handler [1]:

```
$('input').click (e, triggered) ->
  if triggered then x
  false

$('a').click ->
  $('input').trigger('click', true)
```

This allows you to use the extra argument to identify the origin of the click (user-initiated or programatic), relay the `e.target` from the anchor click, or send data to the event handler.

[1] http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').click (e) ->
      if $(@).data 'triggeredBy'?
          #do something         
      false

$('a').click (e) ->
    $('input').data 'triggeredBy', e.target
    $('input').click()
```

There may be a way to save the previous target to the actual event object, but I would just save to a jQuery data attribute anyway, just to be more understandable. Basically attach the triggerer to the triggeree before triggering. That way you can get it back after the fact.

If you need to be even more specific about the triggerer (you have multiple objects triggering the same event) you can do something like this:

UPDATE WITH CUSTOM EVENT FOR ROUND TRIP

```
input = $('input')
thingyOne = $('#thingyOne')
thingyTwo = $('#thingyTwo')

input.on 'inputClick', (e, triggerer) ->
      that = $(@)
      if triggerer.is thingyOne
          #do something         
      else triggerer.is thingyTwo
          #do something else
      else triggerer.is that
          #do something if triggerer and triggeree are the same
      false

attachAndTrigger = (triggerer,triggeree) ->
    triggerer.on 'click', ->
        triggeree.trigger 'inputClick', triggerer  

attachAndTrigger thingyOne, input
attachAndTrigger thingyTwo, input
attachAndTrigger input, input
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so rigorously. This is just not a one way trip. A user can click on any of the links (or the input) more than once. So, I think that the issue is once you clicked the link there's no way of going back (clicking the input). So I'll just remove the data attribute at the end of the click. I'll accept your answer, but I'll keep the question open for another day, just in case there's a buildin way of doing this.

Comment: I don't understand how my answer fails in your scenario. Do you just need a way to blank out the data attribute if the user then clicks the root element?

Comment: Yes that's about it (no need to update anything). Anyway, your answer is pretty much spot on. Thanks again.

Comment: Wait I have a great idea! Don't use click! Use a custom event!

Comment: @Fresheyeball using `data` is unnecessary overhead, you can pass `e.target` (or anything else) directly to the triggered handler - see my answer.

Comment: updated. @RicardoTomasi I didn't know the arguments there where open ended! Thats really cool!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know coffee script, but this should tell you what element was triggered and if you want to know more about the element you can check their attribute such as a class or ID.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    var target = e.target,
        $target = $(target);

    console.log( 'This element is: ' + target.nodeName );    
    console.log( 'This class is: ' + $target.attr('class') );
    console.log( 'This ID is: ' + $target.attr('id') );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However as I already stated in my question e.target is the same in both of the cases. You can also check this out yourself in the link I posted.